# Change in source code using gmock for non virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, googlemock

We are going through the Gmock Library to build Mock function for Non virtual functions i.e. *hi-perf dependency injection*.
We found that we need to templatize our production code for mocking the non virtual function.

My question is, is there any way to mock non virtual functions without changing the source code, i.e. not to add the template to the class.

Thanks,

~Mandar

Comment: Your question says: _is there any way to mock **virtual** functions_ but did you mean: _is there any way to mock **non-virtual** functions_?

Comment: @MishaBrukman thanks for the mistake. I need for non virtual functions

Answer (score 1):

To be able to mock out functions, you need to add a level of indirection, and in C++ (since you're using GMock), your options are:

- use virtual methods
- use [hi-perf dependency injection](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods) via templates, which you're trying to avoid

Marking non-virtual methods `virtual` is a tiny cost in terms of source code modification but comes at the expense of a small runtime overhead; however, you would have to demonstrate via benchmarks that adding the `virtual` marker to your methods materially affects your software's performance before rejecting it, because it is the simplest and cleanest way of enabling mocking and testing.